# GPUImage background subtraction iOS

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I start capturing the camera with `startCameraCapture` and using `setFrameProcessingCompletionBlock` for take a `GPUImageOutput` (my background image).
Now I want for each frame to subtract my background image from the other captured frames.

How I can achieve this?
Thanks